# Vue JS - indexOf array is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, indexof

I'm trying to check if a number is present in an array (which I've done a thousand times before using `.indexOf()`) but I seem to be missing something now.

**Vue method**

```
showSeat(seat) {
    if( !this.selectedSeats.length ) { 
        this.selectedSeats.push(seat)
    } else {
        let index = this.selectedSeats.indexOf(seat)
        ( index >= 0 ) ? this.selectedSeats.splice(index,1) : this.selectedSeats.push(seat)
    }
}
```

Initially, `this.selectedSeats` is equal to `[]`, and the first condition runs perfectly. However, when I try to add another *seat*, I get `[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "showSeat": "TypeError: this.selectedSeats.indexOf(...) is not a function"`. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `seat` a string or an object?

Comment: Maybe console.log `this.selectedSeats` before calling `indexOf` on it will provide a clue

Comment: well, from the error, I can only assume that `this.selectedSeats` is not an array. What do you get if you do `console.log(Array.isArray(this.selectedSeats));` before `let index` ?

Comment: @Jns it is an Integer

Comment: @NickParsons it **is** an array. I can see it in the dev tools and actually logged `this.selectedSeats[0]` which returns the seat I pushed initially. (I did however run your script and it returns `true`)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I did logged both the array and the first element using `this.selectedSeats[0]`. Both returned what was expected.

Comment: How about logging `this.selectedSeats.indexOf` (should be a native function).  Also, is `showSeats` asynchronous?  Maybe some more (but not too much) code for context?  A jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty it's part of a larger application. Let me set up a fiddle to try and replicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those rare cases in JavaScript where leaving off a semicolon can cause huge problems. These two lines are being evaluated as a single expression:

```
 let index = this.selectedSeats.indexOf(seat)
 ( index >= 0 ) ? this.selectedSeats.splice(index,1) : this.selectedSeats.push(seat)
```

It's trying to execute `this.selectedSeats.indexOf(seat)(index>=0)`

Add a semicolon at the end of your `indexOf(seat);` and you should be fine.

Comment: Also can't the OP just not use parentheses around the first part of the ternary?

Comment: Absolutely, leaving off the parens would also solve the problem.

Comment: Awesome! I'm starting write without semi-colons so I guess it was just a matter of time before I ran into this. Thanks.

Comment: @brunouno Better to always use semi-colons

Comment: That's a good discussion. What are the advantages in both cases? Obviously, it seems safer to keep on using them, but I guess knowing that it was being evaluated as a single expression would've spared me an hour of useless debugging. This case makes me think my code would become cleaner if I run into these kind of things.

Comment: There is a huge debate about that topic, and it all comes down to having a good understanding of ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion). [This is a pretty good "opposing viewpoint"](https://feross.org/never-use-semicolons/) article, especially the line about: "If you 'never use semicolons', there’s only one rule: Never start a line with `[`, `(`, or `\``". (backtick because of [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates))